# How to adjust background image on the list-style:outside - CSS

Tags: css, list, html-lists

Is it not possible to adjust a background image when `list-style-position` is `outside`?

**Example:**

```
li {list-style:decimal;background:url(images/bg-li.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
```

If I change the background position to a negative value in order to shift it to the left and be behind the decimal number, which is outside, the image just gets cut off on the left.

When `list-style-position` is `inside` or  `none`,  both `padding` and `background-position` help, however with an `outside` position nothing seems to work.

The problem is that I have a list where each list item is quite long and I want the numbering to be outside of the list so that the second line of text doesn't overflow the numbering.

Are there any solutions to this?

**UPDATE**

The only way I was able to achieve what I need was to do this (which pretty much gives up on the styling of the `outside` list style):

```css
ol li { list-style:none; list-style-position:inside;background:url(images/bg-li.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;padding:0; margin:0}
ol li strong{display:table-cell;font-weight:normal}
ol li span{display:table-cell; padding:14px 12px 5px 12px; font-size:0.875em}
```

I gave up on the `list-style: decimal` and just used the numeric value in a `<span>` + the text body of each list item in a `<strong>`, displaying them as `table cells` - so that the span item has a background image and the strong item is displayed as a justified text wrapped properly.

Can't say I like this type of coding but I guess it's the easiest way out?

Comment: A fiddle would be better to help...

Comment: this doesn't say anything to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: what @BhojendraNepal is trying to say is for you to show  us your code or an example of what your trying to ask . you can show us in a fiddle, like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo elements (eg `:before`) to achieve this:

```
ol li {
    line-height: 24px;
    position: relative;
}

ol li:before {
    background: green;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute; left: -24px; top: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rwacarter/wofmsvth/